# Asp .net core webapi log to file in Dev write to application insights once deployed in azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a new WebApi using .net7 and asp.net core I have used NLog before and know how to set up logging but since I'm deploying to azure and will use Application Insights to do the logging there but I don't want to use it in DEV.

How can it config my app so that it logs to file in dev and APPI once deployed?

Comment: Could you please share your `.csproj` and `Program.cs` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below steps to Log traces to a Text file while accessing the App in development environment and to Application Insights when deployed to Azure App Service.

Thanks @Jignesh Trivedi for the `nlog.config` file.

***Configure to send logs to a Text file.***

- Install the NuGet package `NLog.Web.AspNetCore`.
- Create a new configuration file and name it as `nlog.config`.Add the below settings in the file.

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="info"
      internalLogFile="C:\Users\YourPath\NLogs\internallog.txt">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" />
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="C:\Users\YourPath\NLogs\internallog.txt"
            layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${message}"/>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="alldata" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Info" final="true" />
    <loggername name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="otherFile-web" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

- In `Program.cs` file, add the below lines of code.

```cs
using NLog.Web;

var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Host.UseNLog();
```

In `WeatherForecastController.cs`, add the logs

```cs
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
 public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
 {
     _logger.LogInformation("Log Information from Weatherforecast.");
     _logger.LogDebug("Debug Message from the Controller Action.");
     _logger.LogWarning("Iam Log Warning.");
     _logger.LogError("Hello, this is Log Error.");

     return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
     {
         Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
         TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
         Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
     })
     .ToArray();
}
```

When I run the app locally and execute the `GET` method, a new text file is created at the path where I have mentioned in the `nlog.config` - `internalLogFile` and `target` path.

***Local Output:***
[image]

***Configure logging to Application Insights***

- Create an Application Insights in Azure portal, copy the connection string and paste it in `appsetting.json` file.

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
  "ConnectionString": "Connection String from Application Insights"
  }
}
```

Right click on `solution explorer`  => `Add Application Insights Telemetry` => `Azure Application Insights`.

- Add below code in `Program.cs` file.

```cs
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]);
```

***My Program.cs file***

```cs
using NLog;
using NLog.Web;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel;

var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
var isDevelopment = environment == Environments.Development;
var logger =(dynamic) null;

#region DevLog
if (isDevelopment)
{
    logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();
    #endregion
}

try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


    #region ApplicationInsights
    if (!isDevelopment)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(ITelemetryChannel), new ServerTelemetryChannel());
        builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();     
    }
    else
    {
        builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
        builder.Host.UseNLog();
    }
    #endregion

    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();  

    var app = builder.Build();

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();
    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.Error(ex, "Error in init");
    throw;
}
finally
{
    NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

***.csproj file***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <ApplicationInsightsResourceId>/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/****/providers/microsoft.insights/components/11-40vscode</ApplicationInsightsResourceId>
    <UserSecretsId>****</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Profiler.AspNetCore" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="5.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Deploy the App to Azure and enable `Application Insights`.

[image]

- Run the Application and check `Transaction Search` and `Logs` in `Application Insights`.

[image]

[image]

References taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcore6)